# Nextjs Auth with Github not working - Error: missing key

Tags: authentication, next.js, oauth-2.0, github-oauth

ISSUE WITH NEXTJS GITHUB AUTH.

Here is my `env` file:

```
AUTH_SECRET=6f030664824f277754395347f23aef0a
AUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/api/auth

GITHUB_ID = 068d37e0c6334b8ba780
GITHUB_SECRET = dbcbbdf02b3ecca7ec5037edc049bb9a40883cd2
```

Here is more on the error

```
[auth][error][MissingSecret]: Please define a secret.. Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev/#missingsecret 
    at assertConfig (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/assert.js:49:16)
    at Auth (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:82:89)
```

I generated a new GitHub secret. Cross check all the code, but I can't find where the error is coming from.

My next-auth version.

"next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.3"